# video element in react doesnt display video

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

I've made a react component that uses the  tag as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Player = () => {
    const { videoId } = useParams();
    const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('videoId: ' + videoId);
        const apiUrl = `http://localhost:5000/video/${videoId}`;
        setVideoUrl(apiUrl);
        console.log('API URL: ' + apiUrl);
    }, [videoId]);

    if (!videoId) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <video width="640" height="360" name='media' autoPlay  controls >
            <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Player;
```

However the video player just shows a black screen and the controls are grayed out. this is how it looks like with the chrome developer tools:

```
<video width="640" height="360" name="media" autoplay="" controls="">
    <source src="http://localhost:5000/video/65db62c76e10b724a8c42db2" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I've already tried all the solutions I have seen:
*adding muted attribute
*adding/removing autoplay
*disabling strict mode
I've tried opening the src link from the video element in another tab and the video plays correctly, so i think this is some react weirdness

Comment: Is there any error in the browser console? Can the video URL address `http://localhost:5000/video/65db62c76e10b724a8c42db2`  be accessed?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. and the URL `http://localhost:5000/video/65db62c76e10b724a8c42db2` I can just paste into another tab separately and it works perfectly as well as in postman

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. Apparently react didn't re-render the video element. I just added a key attribute with the videoUrl as a value. It looks like this now: `<video key={videoUrl} controls autoPlay={true} name='media'>` .